# Finding when velocity is zero

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, physics

Given trajectory $s(t) = 2t^3 - 15t^2 + 36t + 2$ find, when velocity $v = 0$.

I'm doing this the following way:
$$v = \frac{ds}{dt} = 6t^2 - 30t + 36.$$
Then making $v = 0$, i.e. $6t^2 - 30t + 36 = 0$ and solving that equation we get $t_1 = 2$ and $t_2 = 3$. I am right?

Comment: Yes, this is correct

Comment: You can check your calculus by plugging $t=2$ and $t=3$ in the expression of $v(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

community wiki answer so that the question can be closed

Your solution is correct.